# Problems installing unf_ext on Win7x64

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems

I know I got this working before on the same hardware/OS but today I'm stuck.

For 1.9.3 I get:

```
$ gem install unf_ext --version=0.0.5
Successfully installed unf_ext-0.0.5-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for unf_ext-0.0.5-x86-mingw32
1 gem installed

User@Jake ~
$ ruby -e "require 'unf_ext'"
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- unf_ext.so (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unf_ext-0.0.6-x86-mingw32/lib/unf_ext.rb:4:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unf_ext-0.0.6-x86-mingw32/lib/unf_ext.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `rescue in require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

And for 2.0.0 I get:

```
$ gem install unf_ext
unable to convert "\x90" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/unf_ext.so, skipping
```

This is with the rubies from rubyinstaller.org plus the recommended versions of devkit.

I've also also done `gem update --system` on both.

Can anyone think of something I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this for 1.9.3 - My first instinct to roll back to unf_ext 0.0.5 was correct I just forgot to uninstall 0.0.6 first